# Can I add plastic moisture barrier under my conventional floors without further damaging wood floor joists?

Tags: floor, moisture, protection

I have a conventional 2x8 floor that is 40 inches off the ground. The crawlspace has 6"x12" vents on all sides of the house, spaced every 12-15 feet. We live in a humid area.

Can I add plastic moisture barrier under my conventional floors without further damaging wood floor joists?

Comment: Do you have crawl space vents? Size? Spacing?

Comment: Do you have floor insulation? Do you have a vapor barrier on the warm side of the insulation?

Comment: I do have vents on all sides of house. I don’t have insulation

Comment: Vents are 6in x 12in spaced every 12-15 feet

Comment: Where are you? Accepted and typical building practices vary wildly. Knowing your location could give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Humidity is confusing. Too much can cause moisture on inside of windows, mold , etc. , too little can reduce moisture in wood and cause it to dry out and twist boards.

Here is an article that explains it:

https://www.coolray.com/help-guides/indoor_comfort_issues_to_much_or_too_little_humidity

You indicate you live in a high humidity area when you say, will adding a moisture barrier create “further damage to your wood joists”. Therefore, I’m not concerned about drying the wood out to the point it will twist and crack.

I don’t think venting is the answer. If you increase the venting, you are merely exchanging old humid air with new humid air.

A moisture barrier on the ground could trap extra moisture and create a place for bugs and mold.

I think a dehumidifier is a better choice than trapping moisture in the ground under your house, but you’ll need to monitor it closely so it doesn’t dry the joists out too much.